# Compute dynamical systems quantities (e.g. box-counting dimension, lyapunov exponent) for multiple recordings of same system

Tags: complex-systems

I have multiple recordings of the same biological system, which were obtained at different times they are therefore not forming one single timeseries. Is there a way to combined them to study the underlying dynamical systems?

At the moment what I am doing is compute the different quantities separately for each series and take the average, but I am not sure this is the right way to proceed, and I didn't find any information on this online or in textbooks.

The goal is to compare the invariants (e.g. dimension, lyapunov exponent etc...) obtained from the recordings to those gained from various biophysical models to see which model is flexible enough to reproduce the dynamics.